# Swift can't update Parse object

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a problem and I could really use some help..

I have the method below and everything works fine, until line 907.. When it comes for the object3.saveInBackgroundWithBlock, it does nothing.. Not even errors! It never saves the object and it never goes inside the block..

Any idea why?

```
func addUserToThoseIFollow(sender: UIButton) {
    //self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.enabled = false
    sender.enabled = false

    let userQuery = PFQuery(className: "_User")
    let userQuery2 = PFQuery(className: "_User")

    userQuery.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(PFUser.currentUser().objectId) { (object: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            // If I already follow some users, make
            // an array with them, add the user I
            // want to follow and save. Else,
            // just save an array, with that one user.

            if object["following"] != nil {
                var thoseIFollow = object["following"] as! [String]
                thoseIFollow.append(self.userID!)

                object["following"] = thoseIFollow
            }
            else {
                var myUsers = [String]()
                myUsers.append(self.userID!)

                object["following"] = myUsers 
            }

            object.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (ok: Bool, error2: NSError!) -> Void in
                if error2 == nil {
                    self.followButton.setTitle("Unfollow", forState: .Normal)
                    self.followButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.7)

                    sender.enabled = true

                    self.doIFollow = true
                }
            })
        }
    }

    // Add me to his followers

    userQuery2.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(self.userID) { (object3: PFObject!, error3: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error3 == nil {
            // If the user I just followed, has already followers, make
            // an array with them and add the current user to
            // them. Else, just save an array, with the current user.

            if object3["followers"] != nil {
                var hisFollowers = object3["followers"] as! [String]

                hisFollowers.append(PFUser.currentUser().objectId)
                object3["followers"] = hisFollowers

               /* Line 907 */ object3.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (ok7: Bool, error7: NSError?) -> Void in // Line 907
                    if error7 == nil {
                        print("ok")
                    }
                    else {
                        print(error7)
                    }
                })
            }
            else {
                var hisFollowers = [String]()

                hisFollowers.append(PFUser.currentUser().objectId)
                object3["followers"] = hisFollowers

                object3.saveInBackgroundWithBlock( { (ok5: Bool, error7: NSError!) -> Void in
                    print("otinanai")

                    if error7 != nil {
                        print(error7.localizedDescription)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `object3.saveEventually()` ?

Comment: is it just that you have NSError? in this call, although you have used NSError! every other time?

Comment: @TikhonovAlexander Yes! Nothing changed..

Comment: In your third save, create an `else` statement: `if error3 == nil { } else { fatalError() }`. If the `fatalError` triggers, perhaps you need to look into the query to see what's wrong.

Comment: @KelvinLau Nothing happened! :/ I don't get it.. It doesn't seem like there's something wrong with my code.. It's a standard procedure.. :/

Comment: And if you use the old version, you can update it 1.11.0

Comment: @TikhonovAlexander I'm about to release my app, so I don't have the time to change all frameworks.. :/

Answer (score 0):

**Attempt #1**

What `PFUser.currentUser().objectId` return ? If it returns `nil` so it doesn't work.

**Attempt #2**

[Available Parse Types](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-data-types)

So far we've used values with type NSString, NSNumber, and PFObject. Parse also supports NSDate, and NSNull.
You can nest NSDictionary and NSArray objects to store more structured data within a single PFObject.

Try to use `var hisFollowers = [NSString]()` instead of `var hisFollowers = [String]()`

Answer (score 0):

```
self.userID
```

Where exactly is this coming from?
Did your check, whether it is an optional?

Comment: Everything before object3.saveInBackgroundWithBlock works fine! I get the correct object.. I've checked..

Comment: Most probably it is not allowed to use multiple queries on 1 Target the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the first query and see if it works.

Each Parse object can only have one background thread running for it at a time. Say you save an object, then immediately in the next line (not inside of its call back), edit it and then save it again. The second save will not be called, since the first save is still running. You don't even get an error. You get zero notification whatsoever that this call didn't happen.

My guess is that you have objects being saved inside both the first query and the second query, and because of that, the second query's save is being skipped.

The solution would be to stick the second query inside of the first's callback.

I think that there's a PromiseKit library you can download that adds javascript functionality in iOS, making it more similar to how you'd chain these calls in cloud code, but I haven't used it.

Comment: I commented out the first getObject and sadly nothing changed! Still, doesn't get in the save block..

Comment: Try changing the three lines above line 907 to just object3["followers"].append(PFUser.currentUser().objectId), and add some break points to make sure it's getting called. Or an NSLog, to print out the value of object3["followers"] before you add the object id, and after, to make sure it's being added.